# Long term and short term effect of estimators on AR model

Tags: autoregressive

How do we find out the long term and short term effect of estimators on AR model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to *Hamilton (1994)*, page 1-5:

suppose a process where:
$y_{t} = b \times y_{t-1} + w_{t}$

Where $y_{t-1}$ is the realisation in the previous period and $w_{t}$ is some random innovation.

The long run effect therefore is the effect on $y_{t+1}$ from a permanent increase in $w$. Hence the long-run effect is ${1}/{(1-b)}$ for this special case (or the expected value of the function). For the short run effect I cannot find a proper source right now but I remember it being the coefficient ($b$ in this case).

However, as far as I know the term is far more common for Vector Error Correction models. Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Please improve your question. What is w? What is theta? See the FAQ, the answers in this site should be as self-sufficient as possible.

Comment: @mpiktas: hope it is more understandable now - i was in a hurry before - sorry.